# Is there an IP penalty for surrendering?

Tags: league-of-legends

It's the second time today that I have a teammate refuse to surrender because it "halves IP gained." I can find no source confirming this, so I doubt it is true but I thought I'd make sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no "penalty for surrendering," but IP gain is linear with time (up to a threshold: 55 minutes), so the longer you stay (even if you're losing) the more you can gain.

That said, it is often faster to gain IP by surrendering if you believe you have a good chance for winning (eg. 50%)

btw: [CITATION](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=129452)

Comment: Oh my, a reference? You, sir, are after my heart. (It's an incredibly old post, and the IP system changed since then, but the intention is still there.)

Comment: @Borror0 it was the only "official" post I could find.  I know there is no penalty because you can see IP change at the end of the game, but I wanted something official just in case...

Comment: I'm a tough crowd, but I am thankful.